# After Login req.user is Undefined(Passportjs + Nodejs)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, passport.js

I have made a user register and login but I couldnt understand why `req.user` shows undefined.

I couldnt understand why it shows undefined.

I have middleware of :

```
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

And also I have middleware of body-parser

This is my register(post):

```
app.post('/register',[
  // username must be an email
  check('kullanici_adi').notEmpty(),
  // email must be at least 5 chars long
  check('email').isEmail(),
  // email must be at least 5 chars long
  check('sifre').notEmpty(),
], async (req, res) => {
  const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
  const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.sifre, salt);

  let kullanici = new Kullanici({
      kullanici_adi: req.body.kullanici_adi,
      email: req.body.email,
      sifre: hashedPassword,
   });

   const errors = validationResult(req);
   if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
     req.flash('danger', 'Bütün Alanların Doldurulması Zorunludur');
     res.render('kayit', {
    });
  }
  kullanici.save(function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    res.redirect('/');
  }
});
});
```

**This is my login parts:**

```
app.get('/login', function(req, res){
  res.render('login');
});

app.post('/login', (req, res, next) => {
  passport.authenticate('local', {
      failureRedirect: '/login',
      successRedirect: '/',
      failureFlash: true,
  }) (req, res, next);
});

app.get('/logout', function(req, res){
  req.logout();
  req.flash('success', 'You are logged out');
  res.redirect('/login');
});
```

**And this is passportjs configure part:**

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
  usernameField: 'kullanici_adi',
  passwordField: 'sifre'
},
  function(username, password, done) {
    Kullanici.findOne({ kullanici_adi: username }, function (err, kullanici) {
      if (err) { return done(err); }
      if (!kullanici) {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username.' });
      }
       bcrypt.compare(password, kullanici.sifre, function(err, isMatch){
        if(err) throw err;
        if(isMatch){
          return done(null, kullanici);
        } else {
          return done(null, false, {message: 'Wrong password'});
        }
      });
    });
  }
));

passport.serializeUser(function(kullanici, done) {   done(null, kullanici.id); });  

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {   Kullanici.findById(id, function(err, kullanici) {     done(err, kullanici);   }); });
```

When I `console.log(req.kullanici)` in my index or post routes then it says undefined. But at the same time this undefined user can pass through **ensureAuthenticated** parts of my website.

**Note: Some words meaning in English:**

Kullanici = User,

kullanici = user,

kullanici_adi = username,

sifre = password,

email = email,

Can someone help met? Why it is being happened and how to solve this issue?

Full code:https://github.com/michelson/dante2/issues/229

Comment: Hi there! Have you tried consoling `req.user` i.e `console.log(req.user)` instead of `console.log(req.kullanici)`?

Comment: No because kullanici is user in these scripts. Isnt it?

Comment: Yeah when I did console.log(req.user) it writes the user. But why? Isnt my user is kullanici here?

Comment: Passport internally assigns the deserialized user data after successful login to `req.user` regardless of what you call the variable within your app. Calling `done(null, kullanici)` or `done(err, kullanici)` only passes the value the variable(`kullanici`) is holding(i.e user data) to the next middleware, not the variable name.

Comment: But if I want to make a admin login and user then I will not use admin. I think like: Just user variable can work?

Comment: Is it wrong? Cant I make a admin login?

Comment: That’s another question but yes, you can make an admin login, it shouldn't be much different from what you already have in fact, this same code should work. The implementation would ultimately depend on how you tell if a user is an admin or not.

Comment: yes but when I will do admin._id then it will say _id is undefined again.